# How to broadcast SSID in windows 8?

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-8, ssid

I created a wireless ad-hoc network in windows 8, for some reason the SSID is not getting broadcast.  Is there a setting some place that will make the SSID public?

Followed [this](http://www.redmondpie.com/how-to-set-up-wireless-ad-hoc-internet-connection-in-windows-8/) tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Ad-hoc connection SSIDs cannot be hidden in Windows, so likely the connection was not set up successfully and you're interpreting it as an SSID issue. Are you able to connect a device by manually entering the SSID? I have a feeling you'll be unable to.

Does the connection show up in the host under the Network and Sharing center?

Comment: yes, I guess you are right.  I am unable to manually connect.  The connection does show.  The one connected to the internet says "Shared" and the adapter Microsoft Hosted Network Virtual Adapter looks okay, it's sent 375 packets but received none

Comment: When I replicate this, the adapter name is "Local Area Connection ##", not Microsoft Hosted Network Virtual Adapter.

Comment: yes, that's the same name as mine, but in small text below the icon says the other.